# Clone table row using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following table with contents as

```
<table id="oChild" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tr>                    
<td><bean:message bundle="masterResource" key="lbl.Document"/></td>
<td colspan =""><bean:message bundle="masterResource" key="lbl.DocumentType"/></td>
<td><bean:message bundle="masterResource" key="lbl.Mandatory"/></td>
<td><bean:message bundle="masterResource" key="lbl.Available"/></td>
<td><bean:message bundle="masterResource" key="lbl.DocumentDate"/></td>
<td><bean:message bundle="masterResource" key="lbl.DocComment"/></td>
<td width="5%">
<button tabindex="8" type="button" name="imgSU" title="Add The Grade" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fnAddNew('','','','');">Add New</button>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="DocumentRow" style="">  
<td id="" style="">
<SELECT name="cboDocument1" class="form-control chosen-select" onchange="">
<OPTION>-- Select --</OPTION>
<OPTION></OPTION>
</SELECT>   
</td>
<td id="" style="">
<SELECT name="cboDocumentType1" class="form-control chosen-select" onchange="">
<OPTION>-- Select --</OPTION>
<OPTION></OPTION>
</SELECT>
</td>
<td width="5%">
<input type="checkbox" class="btn btn-default mr20" name="txtMandatory1" onClick="" />
</td>
<td width="5%">
<input type="checkbox" class="btn btn-default mr20" name="txtAvailable1" onClick="" />
</td>
<td width="10%">
<input class="form-control" id="txtDateFrom" data-provide="datepicker" type="text" readonly name="txtDocumentDate1" value="" size="" maxlength="">
</td>
<td>
<textarea rows="4" cols="60" onchange="" name="txtOthCovComments" class="combo" onkeypress=""></textarea>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to add more row in the same table as the same content in second row after Clicking on Add new button in first row

and how to change or increment form reference parameters like cboDocument1 ,cboDocument2, cboDocument3 txtMandatory1, txtMandatory2,txtMandatory3

and one more how to add image and function on the same in last td which is empty in first row 
please help

Comment: html code pls .. or share jsfiddle

Comment: You should be a bit more constructive in your questions otherwise this will turn into a downvote fest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your button an `id="add-new"` and try this:

```
$("#add-new").on("click", function() {
   $tr = $(this).closest("tr").next().clone();    
   $tr.insertAfter($(this).closest("tr"));   
});
```

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyqN6/)

Comment: but how to change or increment form reference parameters
like cboDocument1 ,cboDocument2, cboDocument3
txtMandatory1, txtMandatory2,txtMandatory3

Comment: and one more how to add image in last td which is empty in first row

Comment: @yatinbc Add image: $(targetElement).append($("<img>", {src: 'www.imageurl.com', alt: 'Alternative text'}));

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
 var t = $('#oChild');
 var clone = t.find('#DocumentRow').clone(true);
 clone.attr('id','');
 t.append(clone);
});
```

**Make sure you remove the id of cloned element. Having same id  on multiple elements is invalid.**

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/Wu2Gh/3/

Answer (score 1):

Would this do the trick?

```
function cloneSecondRowAndAddToTheBottomOfTheTable() {
    var $rowClone = $($("table#oChild tr")[2]).clone();
    $("table#oChild").append($rowClone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button[name='imgSU']").click(function(){
        var trClone = $('#oChild tr#DocumentRow').clone(true);
        $(trClone).attr('id',''); 
        $('#oChild tr:first').before(trClone);
        });
    });
</script>
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/92/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).on('click', '.remove_slot', function () {
     if(confirm("Do  you really want tor remove this  row.. ?"))
     {   // where "#add_newrow" is a id of table 
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        $("#add_newrow").append('<tr><td> what </td> <td>ever </td> <td>you want </td></tr>');  
           }
     return false;
 });
```

// the code first remove your current selected row and then append a new row